# Java: Searching for an entry in a List of Objects only by one attribute

Tags: java, list, search, arraylist

I have the following List

```
List<A> list= new ArrayList<>();

public class A{
private String name;
private List<B> listB = new ArrayList<>(); }
```

I now want to search for an entry in list by which I only identify by it's name. The background is, that I get an Object of A which I want to add in `listB`. To make it more nice, I want to search if there is already a entry with this name in A and then add the entries which are given to the method there:

Example in text:

```
list:
    name1
        entry11
        etnry12
        entry13
    name2
        entry21
        entry22

Now I want to Add the following listB to listA
    name1 
        entry14
        entry15

Behaviour now:
list:
    name1
        entry11
        etnry12
        entry13
    name2
        entry21
        entry22
    name1 
        entry14
        entry15

Desired bahaviour:
list:
    name1
        entry11
        etnry12
        entry13
        entry14
        entry15
    name2
        entry21
        entry22
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Try to make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. And it would be good to know how A and B are related.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a `Set<A>` instead of `List<A>` as the `name` should be unique for each instance of A in the collection ?

To achieve your need, you could override `equals()` and `hashcode()`  method in `A` by relying on the the `name` field.

In this way, when you want to add elements from a list of `A` with a specific label to a list of `A` with this same specific label, you could create a `A` object with the expected name and retrieve it from the both lists.

Here is a sample code :

```
String name = "nameFromObjectWhereIWantToAddElements";
A aToSearch = new A(name);

A targetA = listTarget.get(listTarget.indexOf(aToSearch));
A originaA = listOrigin.get(listOrigin.indexOf(aToSearch));

targetA.addElements(originaA.getElements());
```

You could also use a Map if the structure suits to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

A list with a key for the value has a data structure [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html). Instead of using array list you can use Map to take the advantages of the JavaSE API.

You can use this method to do so if you use map. "A Set is a Collection that cannot contain duplicate elements." for more info refer to [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html).

```
public static void add(Map<String, HashSet<String>> listB) {

    for (String entry : listB.keySet()) {
        if (listA.containsKey(entry)) {
            listA.get(entry).addAll(listB.get(entry));
        } else {
            listA.put(entry, listB.get(entry));
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: I used Set to remove duplicate entries as the values for the keys. if you want to keep duplicate you can use `ArrayList<>()`. Moreover, Set do not keep the order beased on some implimentations and the order of the entries may vary time to time.